# HTML Audio to play after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

How to play audio when button 1 is clicked, and pause/stop when buttons 2 or 3 are clicked?

```
<a href="#" class="button1">Button 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button2">Button 2</a>
<a href="#" class="button3">Button 3</a>


<audio controls autoplay loop>
   <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/audio/audio1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
   <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/audio/audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button1").click(function() {
    $("audio")[0].play();

});

$(".button2").click(function() {
    $("audio")[0].pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button1").click(function(){
   $('audio')[0].play();
}) 

$(".button2").click(function(){
   $('audio')[0].pause();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8GycB/3/